# Laravel: como inserir no banco de dados de forma assíncrona?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-eloquent

Estou desenvolvendo um site em PHP, utilizando o Eloquent para banco de dados, e estou com um certo problema de lentidão na hora do usuário realizar o login no banco de dados.

O que quero dizer é...
O usuário está demorando quase 3 segundos para conseguir logar, e como sou um tanto quanto perfeccionista, estou tentando melhorar isso.

O fato é, na hora que o usuário faz o login, eu escrevo um insert no banco de dados com as informações do login dele, (data/hora, sistema utilizado, localização e etc... para que o próprio usuário tenha controle de suspeita de atividades irregulares em seu cadastro).

Realizando alguns testes, notei que a demora é por causa desse Select (para logar) e depois Insert (para o histórico de login) que é realizado, ou seja, o select sei que que é necessário e já testei, está muito bem optimizado...

Mas o insert, estou tentando realizar de forma assíncrona, para que o PHP mande o comando e siga a diante com o comando em segundo plano.

Existe alguma solução em php ou do próprio laravel/eloquent para isto?

**Edit:**
Segue função Login em questão:

```
    public function login(){
    $login = Login::select('idUser', 'userUrl', 'trueURL', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'password_hash')->where('email', '=', $_POST['email'])->first();
    if($login){
        if(password_verify($_POST['password'], $login->password_hash)){
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['user_data'] = ['idUser' => $login->idUser,
                                      'trueURL' => $login->trueURL,
                                      'userUrl' => $login->userUrl,
                                      'firstName' => $login->firstName,
                                      'lastName' => $login->lastName,
                                      'email' => $login->email];

            $now = date('Y/m/d h:i:s', time());
            $browser = get_browser(null, true);
            $guest_ipAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            $ipDetails = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$guest_ipAddress}/json"));

            $inputs = [ 'id_user' => $login->idUser,
                        'public_ip' => $guest_ipAddress, 
                        'timestamp' => $now, 
                        'device_platform' => $browser["platform"], 
                        'device_parent' => $browser["parent"],
                        'device_type' => $browser["device_type"],
                        'country' => $ipDetails->country,
                        'region' => $ipDetails->region,
                        'city' => $ipDetails->city
            ];
            $registerLoginHistory = RegisterUserLogin::create($inputs);
            JSON(array('status' => true));
        }else{
            JSON(array('status' => false));
        }
    }else{
        JSON(array('status' => false));
    }
}
```

Comment: Creio que você esteja procurando por [jobs/queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues)

Comment: Posso ver sua rotina completa!?

Comment: @MarceloBoni desculpe a demora, minha conexão caiu e só voltou agora... Sou um pouco novo no laravel, então estou dando uma pesquisada a respeito

Comment: @VirgilioNovic adicionado o código no corpo da pergunta! :)